# $match not filtering records satisfying a condition in a generated field after $project stage

Tags: mongodb

I have a movies collection and I want to find all the movies with one-word names (eg: 'Adrift' should be returned but not 'Bird Box'). I did the following and nothing is returned upon executing the command in the Mongo shell. I saw that the output of only the '$project' stage works fine where all one-word movie titles have 'titleSize = true'. So, I think something is wrong with the way I wrote the '$match' stage. I am new to Mongo and may not have understood the concept. Any help in understanding what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

```
db.movies.aggregate([(
{$project:
 {_id:0,
  title:1, 
  "titleSize":{
               $eq:[{$size:{$split: ["$title"," "]}},1]
              }
 }
},
{$match:
 {"titleSize":true}
}
)])
```

Comment: What’s your mongodb version?

Comment: @chridam enterprise 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a better alternative: [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/). Use it as the query with the `find()` method:

```
db.movies.find({
    '$expr': {
        '$eq': [
            { '$size': { '$split': ["$title", " "] } },
            1
        ]
    }
})
```

Or if you're still going with the current aggregate pipeline, tweak it by removing the opening and closing brackets and some extra braces, you should finally have:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        title: 1,
        titleSize: {
            $eq: [
                { $size: {
                    $split: ["$title", " "]
                } },
                1
            ]
        }
    } },
    { $match: { titleSize: true } }
])
```

Comment: aah! I see I had an extra set of '(' brackets in my pipeline. Thanks @chridam